# Change a project name in the Google API Console without using CLI tools

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Every new project created in the Google API console has the name 'My Project', no option appears available to change the name either at the point of creation or afterwards.

This results in dozens of projects all named the same thing and makes maintenance a nightmare.

How can the project names be changed, without resorting to CLI tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that with "Google API console" you mean console.developers.google.com?

If so, you should use console.cloud.google.com, there you have to pick a name when you create a new project. It also allow you to update existing names (can be found under "IAM-Admin/settings").

Comment: How typical of Google's awful UX to require one interface to create a project and another to name it. Annoyingly I don't appear to be able to create a project accessing the gmail API via your URL. Google, if you're reading this, hire some UX and listen to them.